# Setting Membership provider's database at runtime...?

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

We're using ASP.Net membership providers (the SQL Server provider), and I want to be able to change only the database name in the class . To do this, I need the ASP.Net membership provider configured so that my installer can use it

i used code as

```
public class CodeFirstMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
    {    
      public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)  
      { 
          base.Initialize(name, config);  

          // hard coded for testing  
          string connectionString = @"server=localhost;database=masterdb;uid=master;pwd=password";

          // Set private property of Membership provider.  
          FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);  
          if(connectionStringField != null)
            connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);  
      }
}
```

in above code i need to enter and change the full connection string values..

it too works fine .....

but my query is to change only the database name only of the current connection string mentioned in web.config file..

So is there a way to switch the databse name through an ASP.Net membership through code ?

Comment: Relying on setting private fields using reflection isn't reliable at all. I believe that if you need complex things, just implement your own membership provider from scratch. It's not time consuming, I did it some times and it's easy.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer hmm thanks for reply just by extending the MembershipProvider we can write our implementation is it correct

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. You can implement a membership from scratch. Inherit `MembershipProvider`, which is the abstract class and base class of any built-in or available provider.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer can you able to share me some of links which helps me tp proceed

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer i have implemented the abstract class of membership provider i just want to know the class where i can alter the database name in it?

Comment: I believe that this is up to you. You need to implement the database switch operation. If some concrete membership operation needs to query other database, just work with other connection object. What do you think?